# jQuery targeting elements inside angularjs template, doesn't trigger

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app which loads inside the index, different templates with ng-view. In the index, I load all of the script files (angular and jquery), including the main.js file which contains jQuery code written by me. If I target the elements from the index file with jQuery, everything works fine, but if I target the elements inside the template, the jQuery doesn't work.

If I use firebug to debug the jQuery and I put some breakpoints at the beginning of the click function, and inside the function, the code works.

If I put the  tags inside the template, with the jQuery code, the code works.

This is my jquery code which I try to run:

```
$('.text-down-arrow').click(function () {
    $('.text-up-arrow').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

I tried wrapping everything in the main.js file as:

```
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {...});
    })(jQuery);
```

or without the $(document).ready(function () {});

Anybody knows what causes this or if I should load the jquery inside each template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery wont do the trick . because at the time the document is ready . that HTML with the arrow is not in yet . angular sets the view at some point

so u want to trigger the click in the angular way with `ng-click`

1. attach the click to the html element

   `<div ng-class="{hidden: isHidden}" ng-click="{ toggleHidden() }">`
2. create a function that toggle a var to be used in `ng-class`

   `$scope.toggleHidden = function () {
    $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
   }`

Answer (score 1):

As Mihnea pointed out, the element that you're attaching the event handler to doesn't exist in the DOM when you run the script.

Luckily you can use .delegate() to *Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.*

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/